# Error when using Quantized Conv2D with tf.qint8 inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization

I am new to quantization and I was learning usage of QuantizedConv2D operation in tensorflow. The code is as below

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1.5,1.2],shape = [1,1,1,2], name ='a')
a1 = tf.constant([[2.0],[1.0]],shape = [1,1,2,1], name ='b')
min_a= tf.reduce_min(a)
max_a= tf.reduce_max(a)
x = tf.quantize(a,min_a,max_a,tf.qint8)
min_a1= tf.reduce_min(a1)
max_a1= tf.reduce_max(a1)
x1 = tf.quantize(a1,min_a1,max_a1,tf.qint8)
y1 = t  f.nn.quantized_conv2d(x.output,x1.output,x.output_min,x.output_max,x1.output_min,x1.output_max,[1,1,1,1],"SAME")
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print (sess.run(y1))
```

I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was
>   registered to support Op 'QuantizedConv2D' with these attrs. 
>   Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:   device='CPU'; Tinput
>   in [DT_QUINT8]; Tfilter in [DT_QUINT8]; out_type in [DT_QINT32]
>            [[Node: QuantizedConv2D = QuantizedConv2D[Tfilter=DT_QINT8, Tinput=DT_QINT8, dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], out_type=DT_QINT32,
>   padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]](QuantizeV2, QuantizeV2_1,
>   QuantizeV2:1, QuantizeV2:2, QuantizeV2_1:1, QuantizeV2_1:2)]]

I am not sure if my code is right or this is a bug.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,

Abhinav

Answer (score 0):

I believe the documentation for [tf.nn.quantized_conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/quantized_conv2d) is confusing, because this operation is only registered for the input datatype `tf.quint8`. You could do the following:

```
x = tf.quantize(a, min_a, max_a, tf.quint8)
x1 = tf.quantize(a1, min_a1, max_a1, tf.quint8)
```

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23157) on GitHub.

Comment: thank you so much for opening an issue on git. However i had a question, my inputs a and a1 can have negative values as well so wont using quint8 cause an issue while quatizing and dequantizing

Comment: I am afraid I can't provide further help in that case :(